# Botones Abrir/Cerrar con hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un modal en hooks que abra y cierre con botones, pero no pasa nada.

```
function CartTotal(props){

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    function handleOpen(){

       if(setOpen === true){
           return alert('Abierto')
       }
    }

    function handleClose(){
        if(setOpen === false){
            return alert('cerrado')
        }
    }
    return(
        <div>
           <div className="shopCart">
               <br/>
               <p className="total">Precio Total de Todo: ${totalPrice}</p>
               <br/>
               <p className="total">Total de Productos: {totalProducts}</p>
               <br/>
               <button open={open} onClick={handleOpen}>Open</button>
               <br/>
               <button onClick={handleClose}>Close</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CartTotal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como dice la respuesta de @AdolfoOnrubia, `setOpen` es la función que modifica `open`, teniendo en cuenta esto, puedes hacer una sola función para abrir y cerrar:

```
function handleOpenClose(){
    alert((open)?"abierto":"cerrado");
    setOpen(!open);//<-- Siempre se cambia al contrario
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La variable que contiene `true` o `false` es `open` `setOpen` es la función.

Debes cambiar:

```
function handleOpen(){

   if(setOpen === true){
       return alert('Abierto')
   }
}

function handleClose(){
    if(setOpen === false){
        return alert('cerrado')
    }
}
```

por

```
function handleOpen(){
   if(open === true){
       return alert('Abierto')
   }
}

function handleClose(){
    if(open === false){
        return alert('cerrado')
    }
}
```

y ya se quieres cambiar el estado llamar a la función también, quedaría así:

```
function handleOpen(){
   if(open === false){
       return alert('Abierto')
   }
   setOpen(true);
}

function handleClose(){
    if(open === true){
        return alert('cerrado')
    }
    setOpen(false);
}
```